# Strange behavior of CreateDialog's WindowSize option

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction, dialog-window

Compare the two dialog windows, created by the same code except in the first `WindowSize` has a value while I omit it in the second one. Note, that `CreateDialog` (and especially its default option `WindowSize -> All`) can lead to [unexpected behaviour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7684/89).

```
DynamicModule[{switch = 1},
  CreateDialog[
   DocumentNotebook@TextCell@Dynamic@Switch[switch, 1, "A", 2, "B"],
   WindowSize -> {200, 100}]];

DynamicModule[{switch = 1},
  CreateDialog[
   DocumentNotebook@TextCell@Dynamic@Switch[switch, 1, "A", 2, "B"]
   ]];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

While the value of the `WindowSize` option is recognized and used on the left, any explicit value prevents the evaluation of the dynamic content (be it a number, list of numbers, `Automatic`, `Full`, etc.). The same behavior is experience if `Module` is used instead of `DynamicModule`. Is it a bug? I need a workaround that works with a fullscreen window (i.e. `WindowSize -> Full`), any idea?

**1. Update**

Even more strange is the workaround that I've found by eliminating part of my code, expression-by-expression. I ended up with the following stripped piece:

```
DynamicModule[{a = 1, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k},
  b = Plot3D[Join@{x, y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}];
  CreateDialog[Dynamic@Switch[a, 1, "A"], WindowSize -> {200, 100}]
  ];
```

which correctly produces the dialog on the left, while (and this is the strangest bug I've ever experienced in *Mathematica* so far) when I comment out **any part** of this code it results in an unevaluated `Switch` in the dialog window (on the right)!

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Below are some examples, that obviously should not change the output, but they do, and are producing the above right dialog. I think this behaviour has something to do with the parsing of `DynamicModule`, but I am quite clueless...

```
DynamicModule[{a = 1, b(*,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k*)},
  b = Plot3D[Join@{x, y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}];
  CreateDialog[Dynamic@Switch[a, 1, "A"], WindowSize -> {200, 100}]
  ];

DynamicModule[{a = 1, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j(*,k*)},
  b = Plot3D[Join@{x, y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}];
  CreateDialog[Dynamic@Switch[a, 1, "A"], WindowSize -> {200, 100}]
  ];

DynamicModule[{a = 1, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k},
  b = Plot3D[(*Join@*){x, y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}];
  CreateDialog[Dynamic@Switch[a, 1, "A"], WindowSize -> {200, 100}]
  ];

DynamicModule[{a = 1, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k},
  (*b =*)Plot3D[Join@{x, y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}];
  CreateDialog[Dynamic@Switch[a, 1, "A"], WindowSize -> {200, 100}]
  ];

DynamicModule[{a = 1, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k},
  (*b=Plot3D[Join@{x,y},{x,0,1},{y,0,1}];*)
  b = Plot3D[x, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}];
  CreateDialog[Dynamic@Switch[a, 1, "A"], WindowSize -> {200, 100}]
  ];
```

Each of these were tried with a fresh kernel, without any user package loaded.

**2. Update**

The following example shows that the variable `a` displayed in the dialog has **no initial value** in spite of defining it two times (note however that the `Initialization` code is not evaluated at all, you can make sure about that by putting any `Print` in it):

```
DynamicModule[{a = None},
  Print[a];
  CreateDialog[{
    Dynamic@a,
    Dynamic@Switch[a, True, "A", False, "B", None, "C"],
    (*Checkbox@Dynamic@a*)
    }, WindowSize -> {200, 100}],
  Initialization :> (a = None)
  ];
```

> `None`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Thus `a` has a value (`None`) inside the `DynamicModule` but not inside the dialog. Uncommenting the commented line proves that the `a` displayed in the dialog is **not the same** as the `a` being locally defined in `DynamicModule`:

```
DynamicModule[{a = None},
  Print[a];
  CreateDialog[{
    Dynamic@a,
    Dynamic@Switch[a, True, "A", False, "B", None, "C"],
    Checkbox@Dynamic@a
    }, WindowSize -> {200, 100}],
  Initialization :> (a = None)
  ];
```

> `None`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

that is: still printing `None` as the value of the `DynamicModule`-`a`, but displaying `False` as the dialog-`a`, which is the default value that `Checkbox` assignes to a variable without any value.

**To conclude: a dialog does not necessarily inherit the variables of its enclosing `(Dynamic)Module`.**

Printing `Dynamic@a` instead of simply `a` helps, as it forces the front-end to claim the dynamically displayed `a` of the wrapping module. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

```
DynamicModule[{a = None},
  Print[Dynamic@a];
  CreateDialog[{
    Dynamic@a,
    Dynamic@Switch[a, True, "A", False, "B", None, "C"],
    Checkbox@Dynamic@a
    }, WindowSize -> {200, 130}],
  Initialization :> (a = None)
  ];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**3. Update: **

The purpose of this construction is to design a gui where the displayed content switches according to user interaction. While there might be easier ways to do this, I am now inclined to solve the underlyings of this behavior. The following example uses three "screens" as different contents (`first`, `second`, `third`). Changes made to dynamic controls in one screen should affect other screens (hence the variable `x`).

```
DynamicModule[{a = 1, x = .5, first, second, third},
  first := Column@{"First", Row@{"x: ", Slider@Dynamic@x}, Button["Next", a = 2]};
  second := Column@{"Second", Row@{"x: ", Dynamic@x}, Button["Next", a = 3]};
  third := Column@{"Third", Button["Reset x", x = .5], Button["Next", a = 1]};
  CreateDialog[Dynamic@Switch[a,
     1, first,
     2, second,
     3, third
     ], WindowSize -> {300, 200}]];
```

Comment: I don't think this has to do with the presence of the WindowSize option.  I get the same behaviour in both windows.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries the same correct or incorrect behaviour? Otherwise, you must be right, see my edit.

Comment: The same incorrect (or, better, unintended) behavior. I think this is a scoping issue.

Comment: I noticed that the same code executed from a FrontEnd window that has its own `Context` works as I described, whereas a standard window does what you reported.

Comment: The wormhole section of tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality might be relevant here

Comment: @IstvánZachar, I get the same behaviour as you. A simple workaround seems to be to set `nb=DocumentNotebook[...]` and then `CreateDialog[nb,...]`.

Comment: "The variables declared in a DynamicModule are localized to a particular rectangular area within one cell in a notebook. There are situations in which it is desirable to extend the scope of such a local variable to other cells or even other windows. For example, you might want to have a button in one cell that opens a dialog box that allows you to modify the value of a variable declared in the same scope as the button that opened the dialog."

Comment: @Sjoerd, I will try to wrap my head around that, but I'm afraid this won't explain (or at least I fail to see how) the behaviour experienced in the update: neither of the examples should give different results, as neither of the changes affect the output.

Comment: I was still working on your first part and haven't looked at your update yet. I don't get the wormhole to work at the moment.

Comment: The `CreateDialog` doc page says: "CreateDialog by default creates a notebook with options set so as to be suitable for the appearance and behavior of a typical dialog box. The option settings include Deployed->True, ShowCellBracket->False, WindowFloating->False and **WindowSize->All**." So, it seems as if `WindowSize` isn't an option of `CreateDialog` (it isn't present in the options section of the doc either).

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  {Mac OS X 7.3, MMA 8.0.4}

Comment: By "works fine", I mean I am not able to reproduce any of your problems.

Comment: @SimonWoods This does not work for me, neither with local (to `DynamicModule`) or global `nb`. Could you perhaps post a working example as an answer? I would appreciate that!

Comment: @IstvánZachar, example posted.

Comment: While you are right that the behavior you reported looks rather inconsistent and could/should be improved, I woudn't consider that to be a problem in practice. What you do I'd consider to not be "within the specification" and doesn't seem to make much sense, honestly. Could you describe what you try to achieve? I think Sjoerds suggestion to look at the wormhole section of the advanced section will most probably provide a solution to what you try to achieve, but it's hard to say from just seeing your examples...

Comment: @AlbertRetey Please see edit, hope it makes things clear.

Comment: I've seen the edit, but from what you show there the first suggestion of  user840 will be a perfect solution, can you explain why that wouldn't work for you? I don't think it makes sense to try to understand the behavior of a construct which probably isn't considered to make sense by the developers. It could well be they would decide that the correct behavior would be to consistently not work at all. See Sjoerd's citation from the wormhole section of  **tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality** for details why your construct isn't making sense as it is written.

Answer (score 5):

The following works for me with Mathematica 8.0.4

```
DynamicModule[{switch = 1},
CreateDialog[
globalvar = DocumentNotebook@TextCell@Dynamic@Switch[switch, 1, "A", 2, "B"], 
WindowSize -> {200, 100}]];
```

However making the variable local to the DynamicModule does not work:

```
DynamicModule[{switch = 1, localvar},
CreateDialog[
localvar = DocumentNotebook@TextCell@Dynamic@Switch[switch, 1, "A", 2, "B"], 
WindowSize -> {200, 100}]];
```

It also fails if the variable is localized in a Module wrapping the whole thing:

```
Module[{localvar},
DynamicModule[{switch = 1},
CreateDialog[
localvar = DocumentNotebook@TextCell@Dynamic@Switch[switch, 1, "A", 2, "B"],
WindowSize -> {200, 100}]]];
```

Comment: Your first example (simply saving the dialog into a global variable) solves even my last problem of variables not referring to the same values (see latest edit in my post: module-`a` and dialog-`a`). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just replacing the DynamicModule in the right place may help...

```
CreateDialog[DynamicModule[{switch = 2}, 
  DocumentNotebook@TextCell@Switch[switch, 1, "A", 2, "B"]], 
  WindowSize -> {200, 100}];
```

or (see the comments below)

```
DynamicModule[{switch = True}, 
 CreateDialog[TextCell@{Dynamic@Switch[switch, True, "A", False, "B"],
 Checkbox@Dynamic@switch}, WindowSize -> {200, 100}]];
```

Comment: And what if `switch` is not local to the dialog?

Comment: switch = 2; CreateDialog[
  DynamicModule[{},
   DocumentNotebook@TextCell@Switch[switch, 1, "A", 2, "B"]], WindowSize -> {200, 100}]; also works. I think it's related to kernel-thread and gui-thread issue. the not running ones defined dynamic variables at kernel not at gui and there might be the problem. Just a guess.

Comment: While it displays correctly, but nothing tracks `switch`, so the content is not updated if `switch` changes, see example: `switch = True; CreateDialog[DynamicModule[{}, TextCell@{Switch[switch, True, "A", False, "B"], Checkbox@Dynamic@switch}], WindowSize -> {200, 100}];`.

Comment: So a working example would be like this: `DynamicModule[{switch = True}, CreateDialog[TextCell@{Dynamic@Switch[switch, True, "A", False, "B"], Checkbox@Dynamic@switch}, WindowSize -> {200, 100}]];`.