# Problems with visual update in GUI

Tags: gui-construction, dialog-window

Consider the following. When clicking in "Browse" and then choosing a file, the path will remain the original one and won't change to the one of the file I chose:

```
nb = EvaluationNotebook[];

DynamicModule[
 {path1 = FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "file.nb"}],
  path2 = FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "file.xls"}]}, 
 CreateDialog[
  Column[{Row[{InputField[Dynamic[path1], String, Enabled -> False], 
      FileNameSetter[Dynamic[path1], 
       "Open", {"Mathematica Notebook" -> {"*.nb"}}]}], 
    Row[{InputField[Dynamic[path2], String, Enabled -> False], 
      FileNameSetter[Dynamic[path2], 
       "Open", {"Excel files" -> {"*.xls", "*.xlsx"}}]}]}], 
  NotebookEventActions :> {"WindowClose" :> (SetOptions[nb, 
       Visible -> True])}]
]
```

Comment: John, before you post a question you should try to narrow down the problem to the shortest section of code that displays it as I have done for you.  You will get a much better response to your questions if readers do not have as much code to wade through.  This is a good question, by the way, and has my vote!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The behaviour is indeed inconsistent: `CreateDialog` uses the option `WindowSize -> All`, where `All` (god knows why) causes the unexpected behaviour with dynamic content. **See resolution of the problem at the end of the post**.

The following even more simple example clearly shows that something fishy is going on: only `path2` can be set via the second button but not `path1`:

```
DynamicModule[{path1 = "path #1", path2 = "path #2"},
  CreateDialog@Grid@{
     {FileNameSetter[Dynamic@path1, 
       "Open", {"Mathematica Notebook" -> {"*.nb"}}], Dynamic@path1},
     {FileNameSetter[Dynamic@path2, 
       "Open", {"Excel files" -> {"*.xls", "*.xlsx"}}], Dynamic@path2}
     }];
```

Removing the `CreateDialog` wrapper causes both `FileNameSetter`s to work as expected, which indicates that it is the special context of the dialog window that causes the erroneous behaviour. Since `CreateDialog[expr]` is just a specialized `CreateWindow[DocumentNotebook[expr]]`, we have to look at the options `CreateDialog` uses as defaults for its internal `CreateWindow`. As it turns out, the blame lies with `WindowSize`. Compare the behavior of the following two examples where only the value of `WindowSize` differs.

This is faulty:

```
DynamicModule[{path1 = "path #1", path2 = "path #2"},
 CreateWindow[DocumentNotebook@Grid@{
     {FileNameSetter[Dynamic@path1, 
       "Open", {"Mathematica Notebook" -> {"*.nb"}}], Dynamic@path1},
     {FileNameSetter[Dynamic@path2, 
       "Open", {"Excel files" -> {"*.xls", "*.xlsx"}}], Dynamic@path2}
     }, WindowSize -> All]]
```

This works as expected:

```
DynamicModule[{path1 = "path #1", path2 = "path #2"},
 CreateWindow[DocumentNotebook@Grid@{
     {FileNameSetter[Dynamic@path1, 
       "Open", {"Mathematica Notebook" -> {"*.nb"}}], Dynamic@path1},
     {FileNameSetter[Dynamic@path2, 
       "Open", {"Excel files" -> {"*.xls", "*.xlsx"}}], Dynamic@path2}
     }, WindowSize -> {200, 200}]]
```

And then I remembered: [Strange behavior of CreateDialog in (Dynamic)Module](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5388/89)

The options for `CreateWindow` (to make it look like it is a dialog) are:

```
{WindowSize -> {200, 200}, Deployed -> True, ShowCellBracket -> False,
 WindowFloating -> False, StyleDefinitions -> "Dialog.nb",
 WindowFrame -> "ModelessDialog"}
```